# Proving that $\mathcal{P}(A \setminus B) \neq \mathcal{P}(A) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B) \cup \{ \varnothing \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that it is false that ℘(A \ B) = ℘(A) \ ℘(B) ∪ {∅}.
I used A= {1,2} and B = {2,3} and got that
℘(A \ B)= {∅,{1}}
℘(A) \ ℘(B) ∪ {∅} = {{1}, {1,2}} ∪ {∅}
which shows that ℘(A \ B) ≠℘(A) \ ℘(B) ∪ {∅}

can anyone tell me what's wrong ?
The teacher said I should have used counterexample and this is an example.I am not sure what she meant by this. Can anyone help me out? And provide a counterexample
?

Comment: No idea why she said that ... looks good to me!

Comment: one counterexample is enough to negate a proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, you got the right answer. You are supposed to show that it is $\textit{false}$ that $P(A\backslash B) = P(A) \backslash P(B) \cup {\emptyset}$, which is equivalent to showing that $P(A\backslash B) \neq P(A) \backslash P(B) \cup {\emptyset}$

Your teacher asked you to prove this using a counter-example or contradiction, which is correct. Here is an example of what a proof might look like using your logic:

$\textit{Proof:}$

Assume that $P(A\backslash B) = P(A) \backslash P(B) \cup {\emptyset}$ for any sets $A, B$.

Now consider the sets $A, B$, such that $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2, 3\}$.

..... YOU FILL IN THE BLANK ....now we see a contradiction, so our starting assumption must be false and $P(A\backslash B) \neq P(A) \backslash P(B) \cup {\emptyset}$ for any sets $A, B$. $\blacksquare$